# Convert from element centric to attribute centric?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have the following XML that is currently element centric (I am exporting this straight out of Microsoft Access as an XML):

```html
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="EnterpriseDocument.xsd" generated="2022-03-17T15:47:36">
<EnterpriseDocument>
<CreationSource>Apple</CreationSource>
<CreationTimestamp>2022-03-11</CreationTimestamp>
<Version>1</Version>
<Name>Generic_Import</Name>
<name2>PM Import</name2>
<freq>Day</freq>
<source>Actual</source>
<value>0001</value>
<ref_name>bu_code</ref_name>
<ref_name3>Action1</ref_name3>
<date>3/8/2022 11:59:59 PM</date>
<value4>86.62</value4>
</EnterpriseDocument>
<EnterpriseDocument>
<CreationSource>Apple</CreationSource>
<CreationTimestamp>2022-03-11</CreationTimestamp>
<Version>1</Version>
<Name>Generic_Import</Name>
<name2>PM Import</name2>
<freq>Day</freq>
<source>Actual</source>
<value>0001</value>
<ref_name>bu_code</ref_name>
<ref_name3>Action2</ref_name3>
<date>3/8/2022 11:59:59 PM</date>
<value4>2.18</value4>
</EnterpriseDocument>
<EnterpriseDocument>
<CreationSource>Apple</CreationSource>
<CreationTimestamp>2022-03-11</CreationTimestamp>
<Version>1</Version>
<Name>Generic_Import</Name>
<name2>PM Import</name2>
<freq>Day</freq>
<source>Actual</source>
<value>0050</value>
<ref_name>bu_code</ref_name>
<ref_name3>Action1</ref_name3>
<date>3/8/2022 11:59:59 PM</date>
<value4>25</value4>
</EnterpriseDocument>
<EnterpriseDocument>
<CreationSource>Apple</CreationSource>
<CreationTimestamp>2022-03-11</CreationTimestamp>
<Version>1</Version>
<Name>Generic_Import</Name>
<name2>PM Import</name2>
<freq>Day</freq>
<source>Actual</source>
<value>0050</value>
<ref_name>bu_code</ref_name>
<ref_name3>Action2</ref_name3>
<date>3/8/2022 11:59:59 PM</date>
<value4>15</value4>
</EnterpriseDocument>
</dataroot>
```

I am attempting to get this into the following format:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EnterpriseDocument xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" CreationSource="Apple" CreationTimestamp="2022-03-11" Version="1.0" Name="Generic_Import">
  <DataSet name="PM Import" freq="Day" source="Actual">
    <Dimension value="0001" ref_name="bu_code">
      <Metric ref_name="Action1">
        <Data date="2022-03-08T23:59:59" value="86.62" />
      </Metric>
      <Metric ref_name="Action2">
        <Data date="2022-03-08T23:59:59" value="2.18" />
      </Metric>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension value="0050" ref_name="bu_code">
      <Metric ref_name="Action1">
        <Data date="2022-03-08T23:59:59" value="25" />
      </Metric>
      <Metric ref_name="Action2">
        <Data date="2022-03-08T23:59:59" value="15" />
      </Metric>
    </Dimension>
  </DataSet>
</EnterpriseDocument>
```

I am currently attempting to use the following XSLT 1.0:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<!--                                              -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<!--                                              --> 
  <xsl:template match="EnterpriseDocument/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently this XSL is not providing the desired output. Could you please assist me getting the desired output?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your attempt is a non-starter.

Comment: Can you define "non-starter"? Not following...

Comment: "*a person, plan, or idea that has no chance of succeeding or being effective.*" (Oxford Languages).

Comment: The XSL does run. It just doesn't make the input XML attribute centric. The system the XMLs are feeding into only accept attribute centric formatting (not sure why they set it up that way to begin with). Are you familiar with Excel and how Excel outputs an XML? The desired format above errors out stating it contains a list of lists.

Comment: I know it runs. It just doesn't make any attempt to produce the result you expect.  There is no way to correct or improve it. At this point you are basically asking us to write your code for you from scratch. That's not done here. Not to mention that it would be a guesswork because the required logic is not clear. There are 4 `EnterpriseDocument` elements in the input, but the output has 2 `DataSet` elements with 2 `Metric` children each. Why? We don't know.

Comment: An observation is that your date formats don't match between the input and output. Also, to solve this in 1.0 use the Muenchian grouping method twice to create an outer group and an inner group. The code for this is relatively small.  If you do this in 2.0 or 3.0 you can use for-each-group instead of MGM.